# Как удалить строки из огромного (большого) файла

Tags: shell, bash, php, linux

Читать весь файл, размером 500-600 Мб я не могу, так как эти данные грузятся в оперативную память, для меня это слишком затратно.

Читаю файл `file_get_content`'ом c лимитом строк (условно по 1000 строк). Как мне после этого скажем удалить конкретные строки. Без использования `$f = file`.

Подробнее:
Я читаю очень большой файл по 1000 строк (первые 1000 строк), по своему их обрабатываю и в зависимости от условий, какие-то строки нужно удалить, а какие-то оставить.

Я могу записывать результат во временный файл, а что если скрипт остановится или что-то еще, а возможности отката нет.

Comment: а чем вас не устраивает нормальный доступ к файлу через $f = file.?

Comment: А sed не спасёт отца русской демократии?

Comment: @alexlz, IMHO sed "по месту" не редактирует. Тоже использует временный файл.

Comment: $f = file не поможет, так как помещает весь файл в память, а у меня памяти не хватает (

Comment: @ifrops,  мне не понятны Ваши тревоги начет записи во временный файл. 

Как делали - так и делайте. 


Читаете по строкам старый, пишите нужные строки во временный. Потом переименовываете (mv) его в старый. **Только делайте файлы на одной и той же файловой системе.** Все ОК. Имя временного файла запоминаете в каком нибудь файле.

Если скрипт свалился, то ничего страшного не произошло. Конечно, кто-то (м.б. сам скрипт перед началом основной работы) должен удалять "неактуальные" временные файлы.

Comment: @avp Что значить "по месту"? Без создания результирующего файла? Так удаление строки в начале файла 600M с последующим перелопачиванием всех строк -- зрелище апокалиптическое. Ежели же речь идёт о том, что sed'у надо задавать имя результирующего файла -- так это не так.(`-i`)

Comment: `sed -i`, как уже сказано -- самое простое и естественное решение. Проверьте, что на вашей системе sed так умеет. Копирования через промежуточный файл не избежать: удаление строки из огромного файла -- жутко медленная вещь. А уж удаление половины строк -- вообще катастрофа.

Comment: @avp если скрипт грохнется, будет ой ё-ё-ёй...

Вроде все методы по своему хороши, но все равно все не то.

Comment: @ifrops: а что плохого, если скрипт упадёт? Ну во временном файле будут неправильные данные, удалите его нафиг и стартуйте скрипт заново.

Comment: @VladID В моем случае критично повторно отправлять те же самые данные, вот )

Comment: @ifrops, вот и @VladD то же самое Вам пишет. Ничего не произойдет если скрипт грохнется.

Вы же **не** собираетесь *копировать* временный файл обратно? Надо переименовывать, а не копировать, тогда все будет надежно.

--

Про  sed. Если можно с помощью него определить какие строки удалять, то возможно, sed будет лучшим решением.  

@alexlz, "по месту" означает на том же месте. В комментарии упоминается только потому, что в вопросе автор озабочен проблемой временного файла, а sed от нее не спасает.

Comment: @avp поторяю: В моем случае критично повторно отправлять те же самые данные, вот ))) Я отправляю данные из файла, повторно их отправлять не могу.

Comment: Ладно, искренне всем большое спасибо, что уделили мне время. Решение кое-какое нашел. Отсеяв лишние строки: grep "id_cat=71" bigfile.txt > bigfile71.txt, оставив только нужные строки. Размер файла сократился. Теперь я могу его открыть ) Всем спасибо )

Comment: @ifrops, если какие-то действия для решения Вашей задачи не подходят, то это потому что Вы ее (смысл задачи) толком не описали.

Кстати, вот открыли Вы файл (целиком). Отсылаете данные. Скрипт падает. При повторном вызове он все равно будет их повторно отправлять (файл-то не изменился).

Так что в этом плане ничего не улучшилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Идея такая.

Вычитываем с файла 100 (200, 1000 строк), фильтруем и пишем в результирующий файл. Потом отмечаем в специальном файле, сколько строк вычитали и с какой позиции (либо просто номер блока). И так далее в цикле.

Если скрипт упадет и его перезапустят, то он вычитает с спец файла метку для старта и начнет обрабатывать далее.

Минусов два:

- некоторые блоки будут фильтроваться два раза и более (так как скрипт будет перезапускаться).
- нужно как то отмечать в результирующем файле, что весь блок был записан. Например добавлять в конец файла метку, а при записи следующего блока - удалять и добавлять снова в конец.

Comment: Товарищи минусующие, вы хоть напишите, что вам не нравиться.

Answer (score 4):

```
cat myfile.txt | grep -v текст_строки_которого_удалить > newfile.txt
```

а вообще более подробно опишите, пару строк исходного файла, и что удаляете по какому принципу. Данный выше пример убог, и явно не для вашего случая, но и инфы мало ))

Comment: лучше избежать лишней команды:

    grep -v filter myfile.txt >newfile.txt